# Python: Functions in while loops

Tags: python, function, loops

I was told that functions are very useful when you want to execute the same piece of code numerous times... However when dealing with while loops, are functions necessary. I'm not sure whether to call functions in a while loop for a text - based adventure game I have to make for school. After all why would I need functions in a loop when they will be repeated until they exit the loop. Would my teacher mark me down for having unnecessary functions?

On a side not as well: How do you change variables in the main routine from within a function... I want to subtract one from the num_water variable by (global num_water -= 1) but it says invalid syntax highlighting the equal symbol –

Comment: You should probably talk to your teacher about this.  Most of us are used to creating functions to suit our specific purpose or to make the code more readable, but I don't know if that translates well to the academic setting you're in.

Comment: `functions are very useful when you want to execute the same piece of code numerous times...` , you interpreted it wrong. So basically a function can be called in "different places of a program"(execute same code numerous times not necessary be loop always)

Comment: You can create a main method and then start other methods based on commands recursively or in a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

William-

Consider a simple C-based state machine, where one function runs the state machine, and based on the current state will dispatch out to any number of functions. The state machine runs forever, as in

```
bool done=0;
while(done == no)
{
  switch(state)
  {
    case SOME_STATE: do_thing_for_this_state(); break;
    case OTHER_STATE: ...
  }
}
```

A while loop is conceptually no different:

```
while (done == no)
{
   do things
}
```

If the "do things" block is simple, and the code can be easily read and understood, then leaving it in the while block is fine.

If "do things" block is complex, ask yourself: is this code easily readable? does it make more sense if it were broken into chunks, each a descriptively named function? If so, you have a good candidate for calling functions in your while loop.

Also, if it makes sense for the "do things" block to be re-used elsewhere, then it makes sense for it to be a separate function as well.

The last consideration on your mind should be performance. If you are writing mission critical code for an embedded processor, a DSP, doing low level telecommunications or launching space vehicles, then, yes. It takes a small amount of CPU cycles to do a function call. For a very small amount of all code written, there are performance considerations.

I hope that helps.